# When I want to rebuild docker image it generates an error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I made docker images and built them using `docker-compose.yml`, everything works fine for the first time but when I add/update some configurations on the Dockerfiles and rebuild the images an error regarding the group or the user I am creating inside the image generates:

```
> [ 2/11] RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel:
#5 0.396 addgroup: group 'laravel' in use
```

Here I am adding laravel as user and group.

The only work around I make is to delete all the built images: `docker system prune -a`

Below are `Docker` files and `docker-compose.yml` file configuration:

`.env` file:

```
PROJECT_NAME=myproject
DEV_DOMAIN=docker.local

USERNAME=laravel
UID=1000

PHP_VERSION=7.4-fpm-alpine

MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=local_db
MYSQL_USER=homestead
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret

XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=172.31.33.213
XDEBUG_IDE_KEY=VSCODE
XDEBUG_PORT=7765
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
    nginx:
        build:
          args:
                user: ${USERNAME}
                uid: ${UID}
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        image: "nginx:stable-alpine"
        container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - "./code:/var/www/html"
          - "./docker/nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
          - "./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
        depends_on:
          - php
          - mysql
        networks:
          - devproject

    php:
        build:
            args:
                PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
                user: ${USERNAME}
                uid: ${UID}
                XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: ${XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}
                XDEBUG_IDE_KEY: ${XDEBUG_IDE_KEY}
                XDEBUG_PORT: ${XDEBUG_PORT}
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
        image: php:${PHP_VERSION}
        container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-php
        volumes:
            - "./code:/var/www/html"
            - "./docker/php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf"
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        networks:
            - devproject

    mysql:
        image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
        container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - devprojectmysql:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - devproject

networks:
    devproject:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    devprojectmysql:
        driver: local
```

`docker/php/Dockerfile`:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION
FROM php:$PHP_VERSION

ARG XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST
ARG XDEBUG_IDE_KEY
ARG XDEBUG_PORT
ARG user
ARG uid

ENV XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST $XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST
ENV XDEBUG_IDE_KEY $XDEBUG_IDE_KEY
ENV XDEBUG_PORT $XDEBUG_PORT

RUN addgroup -g $uid $user && adduser -G $user -g $user -s /bin/sh -D $user

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

RUN chown $user:$user /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apk add --no-cache --update icu-dev gettext gettext-dev git curl libpng-dev libzip-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libxml2-dev icu-dev postgresql-dev curl-dev \
            libmemcached-dev build-base autoconf zip unzip oniguruma-dev &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build-dependencies build-base gcc wget autoconf

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.4

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd ctype fileinfo mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath xml curl json intl gettext tokenizer zip simplexml

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl &&\
    docker-php-ext-configure gettext &&\
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apk del build-dependencies &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug_remote.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=$XDEBUG_PORT" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=$XDEBUG_IDE_KEY" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_host=$XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

`docker/nginx/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

RUN addgroup -g $uid $user && adduser -G $user -g $user -s /bin/sh -D $user

RUN chown $user:$user /var/www/html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, are these compose files coming from some broken online tutorial? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68081763/596285

Comment: no they are custom images I built for my dev environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image field in the compose file, e.g.

```
image: php:${PHP_VERSION}
```

Is the image you are creating. You have named your created images the same as your base images in the Dockerfile, overwriting the upstream names. This is a bug in your compose file, and confusing to others since running an image with that name does different things depending on whether you pull the upstream image or run your locally built image.

Instead your compose file should name images with something in your own registry namespace to avoid collisions. In Hub that involves prepending your Hub username:

```
image: <hubuser>/<appname>:<tag>
```